# Regex match the keyword everywhere except inside a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I create a regex that will match the keyword "politics" everywhere except for in the URL below?  I am trying to use a negative lookahead.

The string is a paragraph of text that looks like this:

> politics are good.
>   http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2018/09/07/omarosa-plans-another-tape-release-next-week-report.html
>   politics are bad.

I want to the 1st and 3rd matches, but not the second, which is part of a URL.

Comment: What is your regex tool?

Comment: The stack programming seems to be raising to next level, where people tend to ask for solution without trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative look behind (if your regex Tool supports it):

```
(?<!http:.*)politics
```

The regex uses a `negative look behind` (looking for: `'http:'` followed by any char any number of times), then matches '`politics`'.

This will skip matching if the line contains '`http:`'.

Comment: Throws an error. * A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width
https://regex101.com/r/XPxPGn/1

Comment: What regex Tool do you use (they are very different)?

Comment: Nevermind.  It works!  I hadn't selected javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be a bit easier to do without regex at all using whatever programming language you are working with (i.e. probably easier to parse the text and ignore any strings that start with "http" and then just use string operators to match the specific text you are looking for).

That said, you could use a negative lookahead, as mentioned in your question, to exclude matches of the word when followed by a forward slash with any number of non-space characters in between. This will work *if the url does not end in the word you are trying to match without a forward slash to follow*. For example:

```
politics(?!\S*\/)
```

Comment: The challenge is the word may not always be proceeded by a forward slash.  It could be anywhere in the URL.

Comment: @Jason edited the answer with a version that will match the word if it is not followed by non-space characters and a forward slash (but this would match the word in a url if it was in a filename or at the end of a path that was not followed by a forward slash).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XPxPGn/2
Often times the word is in the filename.